# Steaming media with PhP

Tags: php

Simply put, I want to stream audio with php. I have already written a script that can stream audio from my server to a desktop application, like vlc or wmp. This was just reading directly from the file and printing it to the screen. Now I want to stream it to my iPod in the same way. When I open the server page it simply says "Server not configured" or something like that. I know it's possible, because when I mounted my external harddrive under my directory root (apache, ubuntu) it works. I am currently on my iPod so I cannot show my code, and am not speaking normally. If you want to see it, it's on my blog, http://tag-soup.net84.net, under the title "RFile". I use the download function to stream media (to desktop apps) thank you.

Comment: you need to analyse error logs of server.

Comment: By the way, you can set your iPod to use a proxy server, and use Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) on your desktop as the proxy to see the data between the iPod and your server.

Comment: What should I look for in my error logs, I can't imagine there is any useful info there

Comment: And with fiddler, it might be good to see what apache isending that my php isn't, thanks